# Vibration on button click not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, vibration, android-vibration

I want to add vibration functionality to my app and just wanted to get started with a simple vibration, I tried lots od turtorias but none of them seemed to work

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val timer_button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.timer_button)
    val timer_text: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.time_text)
    val vibrator  = getSystemService(VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager

   timer_button.setOnClickListener {
       //val pattern = longArrayOf(0, 200, 100, 300)
       vibrator.getDefaultVibrator().vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1000,VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
       Toast.makeText(this, vibrator.getDefaultVibrator().getId().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

   }}
```

Also I added the vibration permission to my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: `VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE` works on SDK>31.

Comment: The old way of doing it is to call `getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator` and call `vibrate` on that. You also might want to use the method that specifies a usage (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator#vibrate(android.os.VibrationEffect,%20android.os.VibrationAttributes)) if you need to do this in the background later

Answer (score 0):

It works in all APIS

> ```
> val vibration = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
>             val vbManager =
>                 getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
>             vbManager.defaultVibrator
>         } else {
>             @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
>             getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
>         }
>         if (vibration.hasVibrator()) {
>             vibration.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(100, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
>         }
> ```